# How to get the treeItem double clicked in mvvm pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I hava a treeView in mvvm pattern by date bind and  bind a double click action by `System.Windows.Interactivity`.

In SomeMethod I want to do something by the Model ， so I want to know  how to get the Model I double click ?

This is the TreeView in xaml

```
<TreeView  Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeNodes}" >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SomeMethod}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Models}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

and the TreeNodes is

```
 public ObservableCollection<TreeNode> TreeNodes { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TreeNode>();
```

and TreeNode is

```
 public class TreeNode
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Model> Models { get; set; }
    }
```

Model is

```
public class Model
    {
         public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

So the tree like this

```
---TreeNode1
   ---Model1
   ---Model2
---TreeNode2
   ---Model3
```

Comment: I findd that `<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{s:Action SomeMethod}" CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>` can have parameter by   `CommandParameter`,but what parameter should I bind?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an attached behaviour:

```
public static class ItemDoubleClickBehavior
{
    public static ICommand GetCommand(TreeViewItem obj) => (ICommand)obj.GetValue(CommandProperty);

    public static void SetCommand(TreeViewItem obj, ICommand value) => obj.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);

    public static object GetCommandParameter(TreeViewItem obj) => obj.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);

    public static void SetCommandParameter(TreeViewItem obj, object value) => obj.SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(ItemDoubleClickBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnCommandChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(ItemDoubleClickBehavior));

    private static void OnCommandChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem tvi = (TreeViewItem)sender;
        tvi.MouseDoubleClick += Lvi_MouseDoubleClick;
    }

    private static void Lvi_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem tvi = (TreeViewItem)sender;
        ICommand command = GetCommand(tvi);
        if (command != null)
            command.Execute(GetCommandParameter(tvi));
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeNodes}" >
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="local:ItemDoubleClickBehavior.Command"
                    Value="{Binding DataContext.SomeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}}" />
            <Setter Property="local:ItemDoubleClickBehavior.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Models}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score -2):

I found a solution by `IsSelected` property.If I define the model

```
public class Model
    {
         public string Name { get; set; }
         public bool IsSelected{ get; set; }
    }
```

and create a TreeViewItem Style like

```
        <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemSelected" TargetType="TreeViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource TreeViewItemBaseStyle}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
        </Style>
```

and I can get the double clicked TreeViewItem by `IsSelected == true`.
But as we know  ,it's never really a good idea to put UI properties into data objects.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Double-clicking isn't the same thing as selecting an item so this is not a solution to your original question/issue.